# Getting error for the following script (do-while loop)

Tags: c#

I made the following script which shows some errors like missing } or ) for the end of the script. What could be the errors?

Any help will be appreciated

```
int CurrentRow =0;
int [,] sumTime =new int [2,TableSize];
int [,] sumScore =new int [2,TableSize];
for(int i=0; i<TableSize;i++)     
   {
   do{
   int currentid= Convert.ToInt16(InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][0]);
   int time=0;
   int score=0;
   bool start=false;
   bool target=false;
   while (currentid==Convert.ToInt16(InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][0]))
   {
      if (InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][1]==startpoint)
      start=true;
      if(start==true && target!=true)
      {
         time+=Convert.ToInt16(InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][2]);
         score+=Convert.ToInt16(InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][3]);
      }
      if (InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][1]==targetpoint)
      target=true;
      CurrentRow++;
   }
   if(start==true && target==true)
   {
      sumTime[1,i]=time; 
      sumTime[0,i]=currentid;
      sumScore[1,i]=score; 
      sumScore[0,i]=currentid; 
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Its not valid code, and the compiler is telling you that. You have a do (without the while) followed by a while loop, so I'm not sure where the fix is, since you have a half a loop inside the for.

Comment: thanks @RonBeyer. May you tell me how can i solve it. BTW, i used also while loop

Comment: @pedrojorge Do you know what a `do-while` loop is meant to accomplish? Do you know the syntax? You're missing the closing while condition.

Answer (score 0):

In a Do-While loop, the While will not have a block. It should look like this:

```
do
{
    // Code here
}
while (condition);
```

Only use a Do-While loop if you want to run the block of code at least once, regardless of the condition in your while statement.

**EDIT:**

I think this is what you are looking for. I can't tell without seeing your project. Try it out.

```
int CurrentRow = 0; // Is this integer already defined somewhere else?
int [,] sumTime = new int [2, TableSize];
int [,] sumScore = new int [2, TableSize];
for(int i = 0; i < TableSize; i++)
{
    do
    {
        int currentid= Convert.ToInt16(InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][0]);
        int time=0;
        int score=0;
        bool start=false;
        bool target=false;

        if (InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][1]==startpoint)
        start=true;
        if(start==true && target!=true)
        {
            time+=Convert.ToInt16(InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][2]);
            score+=Convert.ToInt16(InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][3]);
        }
        if (InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][1]==targetpoint)
        target=true;
        CurrentRow++;
    }
    while (currentid==Convert.ToInt16(InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][0]));

    if(start == true && target == true)
    {
        sumTime[1, i]=time;
        sumTime[0, i]=currentid;
        sumScore[1, i]=score;
        sumScore[0, i]=currentid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Tyler Pantuso. May you edit in the way that you say? since i need a condition to break and that's why i used the for loop to count untill get to the specifc number.

Comment: Pedro, I just shifted things around with your code. Take a look at the edit. Does this work?

Comment: Thanks @Tyler Pantuso for the answer. I have 84 records in my datatable but when i run the code I get this error, which say 'There is no row at position 84.' in line 'while (currentid==Convert.ToInt16(InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][0]))'. While I am pretty sure that this line exist. what can be the problem?

Comment: Is position 0 is row 1?

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to remove the `do` statement. The for loop does not require a do.

```
int CurrentRow =0;
int [,] sumTime =new int [2,TableSize];
int [,] sumScore =new int [2,TableSize];
for(int i=0; i<TableSize;i++)     
   {       
   int currentid= Convert.ToInt16(InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][0]);
   int time=0;
   int score=0;
   bool start=false;
   bool target=false;
   while (currentid==Convert.ToInt16(InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][0]))
   {
      if (InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][1]==startpoint)
      start=true;
      if(start==true && target!=true)
      {
         time+=Convert.ToInt16(InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][2]);
         score+=Convert.ToInt16(InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][3]);
      }
      if (InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][1]==targetpoint)
      target=true;
      CurrentRow++;
   }
   if(start==true && target==true)
   {
      sumTime[1,i]=time; 
      sumTime[0,i]=currentid;
      sumScore[1,i]=score; 
      sumScore[0,i]=currentid; 
   }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks @user1793963 for the answer. I have 84 records in my datatable but when i run the code I get this error, which say 'There is no row at position 84.' in line 'while (currentid==Convert.ToInt16(InteractionData.Rows[CurrentRow][0]))'. While I am pretty sure that this line exist. what can be the problem?

Comment: A table with 84 rows does not have a row at position 84. The rows are numbered 0-83. Arrays, lists etc in C# use zero-based numbering. For example an array with 4 elements will have elements at position 0, 1, 2 and 3, but not at position 4.